# SQL query to get the count by applying group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the below result:

source table :

```
Cnt  A    B
4   ABC YU/FGH
5   ABC YU/DFE
5   ABC KL
2   LKP BN/ER
4   JK  RE
```

Result:

```
Cnt  A  B
9   ABC YU
5   ABC KL
2   LKP BN
4   JK  RE
```

Here I want the count by grouping 'B' and want to display the 'B' record only till the special character (/)

Comment: Great. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Is the / always third char?

Comment: Sql server, no / can be at any place

Comment: @DanielShillcock :

select count(cnt) as cnt , [A],
case when [B] like 'YU%' then 'YU'
Case when [B] like 'KL%' then 'KL'
case when [B] like 'BN%' then 'BN'
Case when [B] like 'RE%' then 'RE'
else 'Others' END AS B from
(select * from (select count(*) as count, [A],[B], 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by [A] order by count([B]) desc) AS RN 
from F
group by [B], [A] ) as M
where RN<=3
) N
group by [A] , [B]

Comment: @DanielShillcock : Please consider the below one: select count(cnt) as cnt , [A],
case when [B] like 'YU%' then 'YU'
Case when [B] like 'KL%' then 'KL'
case when [B] like 'BN%' then 'BN'
Case when [B] like 'RE%' then 'RE'
else 'Others' END AS B 
from  N
group by [A] , [B]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you will have to filter out the all the characters after the "/" symbol and then apply a `SUM` and a `GROUP BY`. You can see this below. The inner query filters out the unwanted string and the outer query does the `SUM` and the `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT      SUM(t.Cnt), t.A, t.B
FROM        (
                SELECT      Cnt,
                            A,
                            CASE
                                WHEN CHARINDEX('/', B) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(B, 0, CHARINDEX('/', B))
                            ELSE B
                            END AS B 

                FROM        #Tab
            ) t
GROUP BY    t.A, t.B
ORDER BY    t.A
```

You can see this working here -> http://rextester.com/IQJ79191

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: @Abcdf You're welcome!!  If this answer helped you to resolve your issue, please mark it as the answer so that it would help others who stumble upon it!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get your string till '/' by using **SUBSTRING**.

```
select 
count(SUBSTRING(reverse(B),0,charindex('/',reverse(B)))),
A,
SUBSTRING(reverse(B),0,charindex('/',reverse(B)))
from source_table group by B;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Oracle - substr(B,0,instr(B,'/',1)-1) B

Put this both in select and groupby

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use a query like this:

```
select 
    sum(Cnt) Cnt, 
    A, 
    left(B, charindex('/',B+'/',0)-1) B    -- Using `+'\'` will do the trick
from 
    t
group by 
    A, 
    left(B, charindex('/',B+'/',0)-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using String and CharIndex Functions.

```
;WITH SourceTable(Cnt,A,B) AS
(
SELECT 4,'ABC','YU/FGH'UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'ABC','YU/DFE'UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'ABC','KL'  UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'LKP','BN/ER' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'JK','RE'
)

SELECT SUM(Cnt) AS Cnt,A,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/',B) = 0 THEN B
                              ELSE SUBSTRING(B,0,CHARINDEX('/',B)) END AS [B] FROM SourceTable
GROUP BY A,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/',B) = 0 THEN B
                ELSE SUBSTRING(B,0,CHARINDEX('/',B)) END
ORDER BY Cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query --

```
SELECT SUM(Cnt) AS [COUNT]
    ,A
    ,CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('/', B) > 0
            THEN SUBSTRING(B, 1, (CHARINDEX('/', B) - 1))
        ELSE B
        END
FROM tblSample
GROUP BY A, B
ORDER BY A, B
```